# Applying borders to a single table cell when using border-collapse

Tags: css, border, css-tables

I have a table with the following CSS rules applied:

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
td { border: 2px solid Gray; }
```

I want certain cells to have a red border, instead.

```
td.special { border: 2px solid Red; }
```

This doesn't work as I'd expect. In FireFox 3 and IE8 it looks like this:

[image: IE8/FF3 rendering]
<sub>(source: [control-v.net](http://control-v.net/stackoverflow/1241757/ie8ff3.jpg))</sub>

In IE7 Compatibility mode (Running in IE8) it looks like this:

[image: IE7 Compatibility mode rendering]
<sub>(source: [control-v.net](http://control-v.net/stackoverflow/1241757/ie7.jpg))</sub>

I want all four sides of the `<td>` to be red. How can I do this? [A test case can be found here.](http://control-v.net/stackoverflow/1241757/testcase.htm)

Comment: The same problem was posted earlier on SO, when applying a mouseover:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/424405/impossible-html-td-mouseover-border-color-change-with-border-collapse

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Won't be possible using border-collapse. You could work around the problem somewhat though, for example by doing this:

```
<td class="special"><div>Two</div></td>
```

Then applying a style like this:

```
.special div {
    border: 2px solid #f00;
    margin: -2px;
}
```

What (hopefully) will happen is the div inside the td will expand outward by 2 pixels and cover the black border with a red border.

Answer (score 26):

There's another post on the site I read a while ago that gracefully solves this problem, but I couldn't find it. Anyway, the approach was to make the border-style `double` instead of `solid`. This works because double has a higher priority than solid. On 1px or 2px borders, the gap between the double lines doesn't appear because the lines overlap.

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
td { border: 2px solid Gray; }
td.special { border: 2px double Red; }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td>a</td><td>a</td><td>a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td><td class="special">a</td><td>a</td></tr>
    <tr><td>a</td><td>a</td><td>a</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice one. This should be the accepted answer. It's still a hack, but it's less hacky than changing the margin.

Answer (score 7):

### Using pseudo elements:

You can use a pseudo element to achieve this.

Just absolutely position the pseudo element *relative* to the parent `td` element. Make the pseudo element fill the entire dimensions of the parent element, and then add the border to it.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/w1hsx7bp/)

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 2px;
}
table td.selected:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>One</td>
        <td>One</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Two</td>
        <td class="selected">Two</td>
        <td>Two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>Three</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you - in my scenario i was applying a class to each cell as I navigated the table with keys, the class had a "glowing" "pulsing" border which was achieved through animations on the border and box-shadow.  Like the border, the box shadow was also not showing on all sides, after implementing your solution it is.  [jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/rwone/opjxb00o)

Answer (score 2):

border-collapse means the td's don't actually have some of their borders. You'll have to find some other way to do it. Giving the table a background and taking away all borders but leaving the td margins gives a nice border. Then setting a border would give an internal border, I believe. Would that work?