# CSS border is breaking for some reason

Tags: javascript, css

Making a table in css like this

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table');
const wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper');
for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  const tr = document.createElement('tr');
  tr.id = `tr${i}`;
  table.querySelector('tbody').appendChild(tr);
  for (let index = 0; index < 11; index++) {
    const td = document.createElement('td');
    td.setAttribute('data-x', index);
    td.setAttribute('data-y', i);
    tr.appendChild(td)

  }
}
```

```css
td {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1.5px solid grey;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

td[data-x="5"][data-y="5"] {
  border-color: red !important;
}

td[data-x="4"][data-y="5"] {
  border-right-color: red !important;
}

td[data-x="5"][data-y="4"] {
  border-bottom-color: red !important;
}

td[data-x="5"][data-y="6"] {
  border-top-color: red !important;
}

td[data-x="6"][data-y="5"] {
  border-left-color: red !important;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-style: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <table cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

But the problem is that there is two angles that doesn't change to red
[image]

My question is why this happens with these two angles but other two angles are fine and how to fix this problem.

Thanks

Comment: How is the system to know that you want that cell's borders to overwrite/change the behavior of neighboring borders? If you remove the border: collapse on the table you will see how the system accommodates adacent borders.

Comment: @AHaworth, thanks for the suggestion, then do you know how to tell the system for this situation or alternative way for achieving something like this? Thanks

Comment: I've added an answer with a suggestion that avoids trying to alter the way the table deals with borders.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/26285473/2358409

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table's cell borders are drawn in order, so you can get some bits of the red 'cut off' by neighboring cells' borders.

One way to do things is to keep the table's setting of borders but set the border color for that cell as transparent and add the border effect through a pseudo after element instead.

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table');
const wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper');
for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
  const tr = document.createElement('tr');
  tr.id = `tr${i}`;
  table.querySelector('tbody').appendChild(tr);
  for (let index = 0; index < 11; index++) {
    const td = document.createElement('td');
    td.setAttribute('data-x', index);
    td.setAttribute('data-y', i);
    tr.appendChild(td)

  }
}
```

```css
td {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1.5px solid grey;
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

td[data-x="5"][data-y="5"] {
  position: relative;
  border-color: transparent;
}

td[data-x="5"][data-y="5"]::after {
  content: '';
  top: -1.5px;
  left: -1.5px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 1.6px red;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-style: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id='wrapper'>
  <table cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, how could I not think about using pseudo element